# PHP connection error with the database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

I only have a database and why is it asking for 2 parameters?

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\video_upload\connect.php on line 5

```
<?php    
   mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //connecting to the database    
   mysqli_select_db('video_system');   //chosing a database 
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

the `mysqli_select_db` function, when using the procedural API requires you to pass an actual connection as a first parameter, [as shown on the man pages](http://www.php.net/mysqli_select_db). This connection, or link, is what `mysqli_connect` returns, so you shouldn't ignore what [`mysqli_connect` returns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php), but rather assign it to a variable.
The function's signature clearly tells you all of this, so please, *RTM*. Here's a few copy-pasted exerts:

```
                            \/=============================|
bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )   ||
//returns bool         argument 1       argument 2        ||
mysqli mysqli_connect ([...])                             ||
//returns type mysqli  accepts vast number of arguments   ||
              //                                          ||
              |======== useful here =======================|
```

This means you'll have to write:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($db, 'video_system');
```

Like the manual && signature show, this `mysqli_select_db` returns a bool. `true` means the DB was successfully selected, `false` indicates failure. It's best to get into the habit of *checking function return values*. No matter how trivial it may seem. So:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!mysqli_select_db($db, 'video_system'))
{//if return value is false, echo error message and exit script
    echo 'Failed to select db "video_system": ', mysqli_error($db), PHP_EOL;
    $db = null;//optional, but generally safer
    exit(1);//stop execution
}
//db selected, get to work here
```

But you can easily omit this second function call, by passing the DB name of choice to the `mysqli_connect` function from the off:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'video_system');
```

Which saves you the overhead of an additional function call, which slightly improves performance. I've also changed the `localhost` string to the IP address 127.0.0.1, which can also help, because using the IP means the string needn't be resolved to the corresponding IP address.
All in all, I think it best you spend some time [reading the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)